# Newline escape sequence not unescaping in proper way in Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, newline, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

I am fetching a String from SQL server 2008 database into my Java code and trying to print it. Unfortunately the newline escape sequence is not automatically converted into newline.
I know the reason is we are not putting the string inside the double quotes in the Database table. Below is the sample value stored in the varchar column :

```
Remarks \nTestRemarks Issue\nTestIssue\n\nRegards \nSunny
```

When I am printing it on log file it is printing along with \n. My application convention doesn't allow me to store String within double quotes inside Database varchar column, therefore I chose to explicitly unescape it using Apache `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str)`. Unfortunately, the result is that 1st and last newline escape sequence is successfully converted to newlines, but rest all newline escapes remain unchanged. If I put space before the newline escape sequence in the DB, then it gets recognized and converted,but not otherwise. Can you please help how I solve this situation.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the opposite once you retrive it, ie StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str) or repeat StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str) after you retrieve it from the database. Either one might work.

Answer (score 0):

my setup is working in wierd manner. for some reason after system restart and eclipse restart and tomcat restart, everything seems to work seamlessly. closing the answer as non-issue